# How to highlight a line connecting a group in ggplot R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gghighlight

I'm very new to R and I'm looking to highlight certain groups in my plot using `gghighlight`. For example, I want to highlight in red only groups 16 and 32 while leaving the rest of the lines in gray. My current code and output are below. I can't seem to highlight specific groups, I can only add color to all lines. I've tried `gghighlight(grp==16)` to try and highlight 16 but it says "Tried to calculate with `group_by()`, but the calculation failed".

[image: example data]

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(gghighlight)

guidelines <- read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet=1)
guidelines$step <- factor(guidelines$step, levels=c("First", "Highest", "Final"))

map <- ggplot(guidelines,
              aes(x = step, y = type, group = grp, color = factor(grp))) +
scale_color_hue(l=45) +
geom_line(linetype = 1) +
geom_line(position=position_jitter(w=0, h=0.05)) 


map + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4))
map + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4),
                         labels = c("Method 1", "Method 2", "Method 3", "Method 4"))
```

[image]

Comment: I added another idea. If you want, have a look.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! One quick aesthetics thing--how could I bring the highlighted lines to the foreground? When I plot my highlighted data, some of the red lines are hidden among all the gray.

Comment: In that case, you may want to split the data set into two and plot the gray lines with geom_line(). Then, you plot the other data set which is one for red lines with another geom_line().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to follow your way and did the following. I am not familiar with `gghighlight()`. I had a quick glance and thought you would need to use logical checks to highlight certain groups. If you can set up logical checks, I think you can use the function. In your question, you simply mentioned that you want to highlight specific groups. One way you can take would be to assign colors with `scale_color_identity()`. I created a sample data below. I basically assigned `red` to three groups (i.e., 1, 3, 5) in `mutate()`. The other groups got `gray50` in the column, `color`.

```
library(tidyverse)

guidelines <- tibble(step = rep(c("First", "Highest", "Final"), times = 5),
                     type = c(2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3),
                     grp = rep(1:5, each = 3))

mutate(guidelines,
       step = factor(step, levels = c("First", "Highest", "Final")),
       color = if_else(grp %in% c(1, 3, 5), "red", "gray50")) -> guidelines


ggplot(data = guidelines, aes(x = step, y = type, color = color, group = grp)) +
geom_line(linetype = 1, position = position_jitter(w = 0, h = 0.05)) +
scale_color_identity(guide = "legend", labels = c("Other groups", "Group 1, 3, 5")) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4),
                   labels = c("Method 1", "Method 2", "Method 3", "Method 4"))
```

[image]

**Potential solution with gghighlight**

I do not have your data. So this idea may/may not work. But I came up with the following idea. I modified `guidelines` once more. I created a new continuous variable (i.e., dummy), which I use for x-axis. This is a bit of twist since we are supposed to have a categorical variable on the axis. But this is necessary if you want to use `gghighlight`. As far as I understood `gghighlight`, we need logical check(s) in the function. Here, I wanted to highlight lines which max value is 3. This highlights group 5. Since you want to have two categorical variables, we gotta modify names on the x and y axis. If you can set up logical checks for the two groups in your data (16 and 32), I believe you can use this idea.

```
library(gghighlight)

mutate(guidelines,
       dummy = recode(.x = step, First = 1, Highest = 2, Final = 3),
       step = factor(step, levels = c("First", "Highest", "Final")),
       color = if_else(grp %in% c(1, 3, 5), "red", "gray50")) -> guidelines

ggplot(data = guidelines, aes(x = dummy, y = type, color = color, group = grp)) +
geom_line(size = 2, linetype = 1) +
gghighlight(max(as.numeric(type)) == 3, label_key = grp) +
labs(x = "Step", y = "Type") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3),
                   labels = c("First", "Highest", "Final")) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4),
                   labels = c("Method 1", "Method 2", "Method 3", "Method 4"))
```

[image]